# Jquery Modal window with mvc 3 razor partial views problems

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, jquery-ui-dialog

Okay so I have been working on using some jquery modal windows for a few functions for a site I am currently working on. The modal windows all open, but they have absolutely no styling and no overlay is shown. Here is how I am defining the div for the modal:

```
<div class="ui-overlay"><div class="ui-widget-overlay"></div><div class="ui-widget-shadow ui-corner-all" style="width: 302px; height: 152px; position: absolute; left: 50px; top: 30px;"></div></div>
            <div  style="position: absolute; width: 280px; height: 130px;left: 50px; top: 30px; padding: 10px;" class="ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"></div>
<div id="postEventPanel"></div> //this is the actual modal window
```

and I am loading the content for the view via jquery.load:

```
$('#postEventPanel').load(loadUrl);
```

and setting the dialog options like so:

```
  $('#postEventPanel').dialog({
    width: 650,
    modal:true,
    autoOpen: true,
    resizable: true,

    show: { effect: 'drop', direction: "up" }

}).show();
```

So the problem I am having is that the overlay does not show up and neither does any of the styles. 
I have used the theme roller to generate my own theme, and I have included that in my application layout page.

Here is a screen shot of the problem I am seeing:

[image: This is a screen capture of the problem I am having, see that there is no styles, not even the default styles for the modal.]

Any help is greatly appreciated guys,
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check if the CSS associated with the modal window styles is loaded / referenced correctly. Also if you are in Firefox and you are using a debugger such as Firebug, check if there's any javascript issues on the Console Tab.

Comment: I have checked that the css and js files are referenced and loaded correctly, and they seem to be.

Comment: I found the issue, there was a conflict in the css with a twitter bootstrap css file. After changing the order of the includes for the css files i have been able to get it to work.